# Runtime 1004 Range of Object worksheet failed when adding numbers to Lrow

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm trying to write a formula into a column by using `Lrow`. I found the formula can run without problem when it only with `Lrow` but I have run time error 1004 range of object worksheet failed when having `Lrow - 6`. The calculation is done in Column B while column A has the data I want to take the average. Col A has data from `A2` to `A & Lrow` . Can someone point out why this yields an error message and how to fix it?
Many thanks in advance! Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Calculation()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("A.xlsx")
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long

For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
Lrow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Range("B8:B" & Lrow -6).Formula ="=(average(A2:A13)"&"+average(A3:A14))/2"  'Here in range Lrow - 6 give me this error

Next sh

End sub
```

Comment: What is the output in the Immediate Window of `Debug.Print Lrow - 6`?

Comment: Hi @BigBen, it is -6

Comment: Well that's not a valid row number. Though `lrow` must be at least 1 so something else is going on that's not present in your provided code snippet. Regardless, you have to check `If lrow > 6` before attempting to subtract 6.

Comment: add this before the `.Formula` line - `If Lrow < 7 then msgbox "ERROR"`

Comment: Hi @BigBen, sorry my bad, it has the value of -5, and yes, you are right, there is a worksheet that has the value that less than 6, after I delete this worksheet then the code works fine, the rest of the worksheets all have a value greater at least 24.

Comment: @Vityata, thank you so much, I will add this to my code to avoid such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Calculation()
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("A.xlsx")
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim Lrow As Long

  For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    Lrow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Lrow > 6 then
      sh.Range("B8:B" & Lrow -6).Formula ="=average(A2:A13)"&"+average(A3:A14))/2"
    Else
      Msgbox("There were less than 6 rows", vbExclamation)
    End if

  Next sh

End sub
```

If you want it to run unaccompanied and just skip over the sheets that do not have enough rows, just omit these two lines from the above code:

```
    Else
      Msgbox("There were less than 6 rows", vbExclamation)
```